# Suma, resta y otras operaciones matemáticas en tiempo real en un HTML con JavaScript, o llamando a un PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Quisiera saber si se puede hacer sumas o restas o cualquier operación básica en tiempo real en una página web.

Me refiero a no tener ningún botón, que al momento en que ingrese el dato en un textbox o un input (ya que lo que ando desarrollando es web) automáticamente aparezca en un label el resultado de la la operación matemática.

Estuve buscando algunas cosas en JavaScript, o alternativamente llamando por AJAX a un script en PHP, pero no he podido encontrar algo.

Comment: ¿Para qué en PHP, si se puede directamente en JavaScript? Una opción es usar `eval()`, con un riesgo alto de que el usuario pueda ejecutar cualquier código de JavaScript. Otras opciones más seguras pueden ser un poco más complejas de entender. Sería bueno que aclares a cuál de las 2 apuntas.

Comment: con javascript o jquery podrías usar expresiones regulares (para comprobar que sea una operación válida) y almacenar los valores que pueda tener tu operación básica, y dependiendo de si es una u otra realizar una suma, resta, etc, o un `eval()` del string completo, pero eso ya depende ti y la seguridad que quieras que tenga

Comment: Echa un vistazo a Math.js http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html y a mi ejemplo por si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: ¿Cuántos inputs habría?¿Qué contendría cada input?¿Cuando dices "dato" te refieres a un número o una expresión matemática?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se podría realizar una llamada por AJAX a PHP para que devuelva el resultado. Sin embargo, creo que es mucho más sencillo hacerlo directamente en JavaScript.

Para realizar un cálculo en JavaScript, debemos usar la función [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval), lo cual podría traer riesgos de seguridad. Para eso, realizamos una comprobación mínima, para garantizarnos que los únicos caracteres que ingrese sean dígitos o signos matemáticos.

```js
var fx = document.getElementById('fx'),
resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

fx.addEventListener('input', function () {
    var error = true;
    try{
        //Si sólo tiene números y signos + - * / ( )
        if (/^[\d-+/*()]+$/.test(fx.value)) {
            // Evaluar el resultado
            resultado.innerText = eval(fx.value);
            error = false;
        }
    } catch (err) { }
    if (error) // Si no se pudo calcular
        resultado.innerText = "Error";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fx" placeholder="Ingrese la fórmula">
=
<label id="resultado"></label>
```

Answer (score 4):

Edito: Tras leer de nuevo tu mensaje, he pensado que es probable que estés pidiendo también una forma en la que introduzca una expresión matemática y que ésta se resuelva en tiempo real. En ese caso te recomiendo que te pases por la siguiente página y conozcas la función [`eval`](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) de [Math.js](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs):

- http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Aquí tienes una muestra de su funcionamiento:

```js
function cal() {
  try {
    document.f.res.value = math.eval(document.f.expr.value);
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.6.0/math.min.js"></script>
<form name="f">
  <p>Expresión: <input type="text" name="expr" value="0 + 0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Resultado: <input type="text" name="res" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></p>
</form>
```

---

Los eventos [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange), [`onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown) (que es el mejor sustituto para el obsoleto [`onkeypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress)) y [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) (es el que funciona mejor para detectar un cambio pulsación a pulsación del teclado), etc... son comunes en todos los elementos del DOM, así que están disponibles también en las etiquetas `<input>`. Estos eventos deben implementarse en la interfaz web, no en el motor PHP.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo usando `onchange` y `keyup`:

```js
function cal() {
  try {
    var a = parseInt(document.f.num1.value),
        b = parseInt(document.f.num2.value);
    document.f.sum.value = a + b;
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <p>Número 1: <input type="number" name="num1" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Número 2: <input type="number" name="num2" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Suma: <input type="number" name="sum" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, justo después de escribir este post vi las funciones onchange y keyup, apenas me estoy familiarizando con JS. Muchas gracias por tu aporte :) me has ayudado mucho con tu respuesta.

Comment: lo copie tal cual y no me funciono

Comment: ¿Cuál de los dos ejemplos? ¿Has copiado HTML y JavaScript en el orden correcto? Como puedes ver en mis ejemplos funciona correctamente (si usas un navegador móvil pulsa la opción de ver versión para ordenador). Pásame un enlace con la prueba que has hecho y te digo qué falta o está mal.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar AngularJS para crear *reactividad* mientras el usuario ingresa los datos de la operación. En este caso, suma y resta.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>


 

 <div ng-app="">
     <p>Numero 1 : <input type="number" ng-model="n1"></p>
     <p>Numero 2 : <input type="number" ng-model="n2"></p>
     <h4>Suma  :  {{n1+n2}}</h4>
     <h4>Resta  :  {{n1-n2}}</h4>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. En cuanto a las respuestas, estas deben ser realizadas en base a [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cal() {
  try {
    var a = parseInt(document.f.num1.value),
        b = parseInt(document.f.num2.value);
    document.f.sum.value = a + b;
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <p>Número 1: <input type="number" name="num1" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Número 2: <input type="number" name="num2" value="0" onchange="cal()" onkeyup="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Suma: <input type="number" name="sum" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></p>
</form>
```

Utilicé el código compartido para  realizar las operaciones matemáticas desde js, funciona perfectamente, en mi caso concreto estoy sacando el iva y el total de una cantidad y un valor unitario, pero tengo el siguiente problema, yo cargo campos de forma dinámica esto quiere decir que creo varios campos para aplicar esta función y solo me lo aplica en el primer campo, ¿Cómo hago que esta función se aplique a todos los campos que se llamen **num1** y **num2**?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, esto no es una respuesta a la pregunta que se ha planteado, si quieres puedes [formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) pero no deberías utilizar la zona de respuestas de una pregunta para hacer otra, te recomendaría leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que lo tengas presente al momento de formular una pregunta, y también puedes hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas más del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.